# youtube-dl command saves as flv and not mp3

Tags: youtube-dl

So below is my command that I am running. It should be converting it to mp3 but it still exports as a video in flv. What am I doing wrong?

```
 $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 -- '.escapeshellarg($url).'';
```

Answer (score 1):

youtube-dl will download the video before converting it. Most likely, you don't have `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg` installed. Make sure both programs are available (i.e. you get a sensible output for `ffprobe --help` and `ffmpeg --help`).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly download the .mp3 file from the youtube site.

For e.g in ubuntu terminal youtube-dl youtube.com/watch?v=qn6CMz18lkQ -f 141 .Most probably 141 is the .mp3 file format code for better quality.